# Use of "recast" in mathematics

Tags: verbs, mathematics

Do we write

- the relationship **recast**, OR
- the relationship **recasts**? ("s" at the end)

> *y* = 3*x*       (1)
>
> Relationship (1) recast
>
> *y*−3*x* = 0  (2)

I have many times encountered the verb without *-s* at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this, *recast* is a past participle: it is equivalent to saying *rewritten*, or *re-expressed*.

*Recasts* would be odd, because the equation is the object, not the subject of the recasting.

It's confusing because *cast* and its compounds are among the few words where the past participle is the same as the present. *Hit* is another case.